What are differences between power curve of turbo vs NA engine?
What are differences between power curve of turbo vs NA engine?
At operating window at max power, which engine have more area under curve?
If we look at both engine with same peak power.

All things being the same, where the engine itself is the same between when it is NA to when turbocharged, the curves are the same, just displaced with more HP/TQ as the boost changes. Noted YouTuber and extremely knowledgeable guy on the subject, Richard Holdener has proven this many times with his dyno results.
You can't compare dislike engines, because they will never be the same.

you are compare two engines with different power, this not in my question
